# update android sdk permission error

Tags: android, permissions, sdk

I have downloaded the android SDK 8 for linux and following the tutorial typed:

```
#tools/android update sdk
bash: tools/android: Permission denied
```

So I tried:

```
#sudo tools/android update sdk
sudo: unable to execute tools/android: Permission denied
```

Comment: Did you try logging in as root?

Comment: Going out on a limb here, could you post the output of the following (run from the root folder of the sdk install): `ls -l tools/ | grep android`

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    3443 2010-11-18 00:51 android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Permission denied is because you are trying to execute something from a noexec mounted partition. Either mount with exec rights or use sh `./script`. In your case:

```
cd tools
sh ./android sdk
```

To remount with exec rights:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev/yourpartition
```

Answer (score 0):

it is generaly caused by the files of java, you need to change the rights of the java files in the /usr/bin/
to do that you can execute:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/java
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/javac
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/javaws
```

sory for my bad english